# msf4j oauth2-security is throwing null pointer exception

Tags: java, msf4j, wso2-msf4j

When I am trying to validate the token, oauth2-security msf4j returns null pointer exception, without giving any more detail. On debugging it appears that getValidatedTokenResponse is returning empty and so NPE is coming: I verified the token and configuration, and everything seems to be fine.

```
private boolean validateToken(String authHeader) throws MSF4JSecurityException {
        String accessToken = this.extractAccessToken(authHeader);
        String responseStr = this.getValidatedTokenResponse(accessToken);
        Map responseData = this.getResponseDataMap(responseStr);
        if(!Boolean.parseBoolean((String)responseData.get("active"))) {
            throw new MSF4JSecurityException(SecurityErrorCode.AUTHENTICATION_FAILURE, "Invalid Access token.");
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

When I used spring security to verify the token, it worked fine..

Comment: What is the MSF4J version that you are using? Can you check with MSF4J 2.1.0 https://github.com/wso2/msf4j/blob/v2.1.0/core/src/main/java/org/wso2/msf4j/security/oauth2/OAuth2SecurityInterceptor.java Also please share the logs

Comment: The problem resolved now. introspect war hadn't deployed correctly, so I deployed it again in the server, and this problem resolved.